# Why libsvm does not support mini-batch?

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

I wanna train a model for a classification problem, the size of my dataset is O(10^8), which is too huge to load. I am wondering why libsvm does not support mini-Batch and how can I implement mini-batch with libsvm?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Aaron! It is a fair question for the libsvm authors but I'm not sure it is a good fit for stackoverflow: it is a bit too open. How about asking at https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/issues ?

Comment: (Imho) it's by design a batch-method. If you need mini-batch / online learning, use some Stochastic Gradient based method (**edit:** i somewhat assumed a linear SVM here; for kernel-SVMs this is probably more complex; but you probably don't want to use these on so many samples). **Edit:** also keep in mind, that SVMs scale very bad with the number of samples (between quadratic and cubic). The only solution to that, again, SG-based linear SVMs (including their problems: param-tuning needed!) and maybe liblinear.